# Create an array in a function in C

Tags: c, arrays

Why isn't it possible to create an array in a function in C similar to what I have below?

```
int **image;
int height, weight;//initialized in a method not shown

void generateMatrices()
{
    image = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*) * height);
    if(image == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Image matrix could not be made\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    int y;
    for(y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        image[y] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * width);
        if(image[y] == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Image matrix row %d could not be made\n", y);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    generateMatrices();
    image[height-2][width-2] = 90;//Fails here
    return 0;
}
```

First of all, I would like to apologize for making this unclear question.  To clarify, I do know how to make these matrices and in fact, it does work.  However, all of that code was originally in my main statement, I wanted to refactor my code by putting it in various methods.  One of these methods is entitled generateMatrices().  For some reason, even though the matrices are supposedly global and even though within the method they exist, when I try to access them from outside that method, such as immediately afterwards in the main, I get a segfault.

Another edit to clarify the code some more.

Turns out that this code in fact did work, and that I was apparently initializing `height` and `width` *after* I called this method.  My bad for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: "isn't possible" - what is the problem?

Comment: Don't cast the return of malloc in C! Can mask errors that you don't want it to.

Comment: Do you mean why doesn't it create a matrix?

Comment: I feel downvoting before 5 mins of the Qn being asked is unfair on part of the OP. WE need to give him some chance to edit

Comment: @Stacker: I disagree.  Posters have all the time in the world to compose a *good* question.   Everyone knows (or can easily discover) what constitutes a good question.  If you post a bad question, there will be consequences, as there should be.

Comment: Maybe the poster doesn't know enough to know HOW to ask a good question.  2d arrays are confusing for new folks if they don't understand pointers.

Comment: @Joe:  Has nothing to do with pointers.  Good questions state what they THINK should happen, what ACTUALLY happened, and what EVIDENCE they have.   Statements like "Why isn't it possible..." without error messages, without a description of the failed compilation, run-time crash or bad-output constitute a bad question.

Comment: @Stacker Please look at my question again.

Comment: @abelenky I was in a rush at the time that I wrote the question, hopefully its clearer now - would you mind taking another look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit, 2-D allocation seems fine. The values of `height` and `width` *might* have gone wrong. I tried your example [here](http://ideone.com/Wlqel) and it works fine for proper values of `height` and `width`

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a pointer to a pointer to [whatever], you're probably not doing to create a matrix -- you're doing to create (allocate, really) an array of pointers. Then (to be able to do anything with it) you'll have to allocate some space for each of those pointers to point at.

```
int generateMatrices(int rows, int columns) {
    image = malloc(sizeof(int *) * rows;
    if (image == NULL)
        return 0;
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        image[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * columns);
        if (image[i] == NULL)
            return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

You'll also want to provide a `destroyMatrices` (or whatever you prefer to name it) that does essentially the same in reverse -- walks through the rows, freeing each one, then frees the array of pointers.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer, would you please mind taking another look?

Comment: Sounds like you've accidentally defined a `image` local to your function, as well as the global one, so your function writes to the local, and the global remains unchanged.

Comment: I'm sure thats not the case (as I do not have any other definitions other than the `int x, y;` - I've added some more relevant code so as to further show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted works, but be warned that it doesn't create a matrix.
If you want to create a matrix, this task is much more involved.

There are 2 simple ways to do this, one of which is much simpler than the other..

**Scenario 1: One of the bounds is fixed at compile-time.**

This makes your code extremely simple, consider the following:

```
int (*image)[height] = NULL;
int width;

void generateMatrices()
{
    free(image); // in case it's already been allocated
    image = malloc(sizeof(image) * width); // you are done, you can now access the matrix
}
```

**Scenario 2: Multiple-flexilbe bounds**

```
int **image = NULL;
int width, height;

void generateMatrices()
{
    if (image)
    {
        free(*image); // in case it has already been allocated
        free(image);
    }

    image = malloc(sizeof(int *) * width);
    image[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height);
    for (int i = 1; i < width; i++)
        image[i] = (image[0] + (i * height));
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer, would you please mind taking another look?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you probably want a 2d array -- and you're only allocating a 1d array of double pointers here.

1) generate an array of pointers-to-pointers the `(int**)`; this is sort of like a 'header' in the 2d array. 
2) Each element in that first array points to another pointer -- this second pointer is a 1d array which you can think of as a single row in your 2d array or matrix.   So, you loop through the first array `(int**)`'s and then do another malloc to create an array for the row [(int*)'s] that's however many columns wide you want.

The important things to realize are that every array can be treated as a pointer to the first element combined with an offset FROM that first element, and that pointers can point to other pointers.  So you have an array of pointers that point to rows, and each row is in turn a pointer+offset (in the traditional array sense you probably expect).

Try the code snippets here: 
http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.com/2008/06/2d-arrays-in-c-using-malloc.html

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer, would you please mind taking another look?